# mkdir from Dymola mos script

Tags: dymola

I have a mos script for running multiple simulations. Before running a simulation, I want to `cd` to a **new** directory, so that all result and log files are saved and never overwritten. Currently it is only possible to `cd` to existing directories, as far as I know. Anybody has a recommendation how to create a directory named e.g. `temp_modelname` and `cd` to that directory from a mos script? I could use `mkdir` in a system call, or is there a convenience wrapper prepared and I just missed it?

EDIT: BAsed on the answer given below, this is my current solution:

```
// cd to temporary directory temp_XYZ
i = 1;
tempDirName = home + "/Documents/Dymola/temp_" + String(i, format="03G");
while Modelica.Utilities.Files.exist(tempDirName) loop
    i=i+1;
    tempDirName = home + "/Documents/Dymola/temp_" + String(i, format="03G");
end while;
Modelica.Utilities.Files.createDirectory(tempDirName);
cd(tempDirName);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The utilities package contains a function to create directories recursively:

```
Modelica.Utilities.Files.createDirectory("temp_modelname")
```

Comment: Why the while loop? The function creates intermediate directories if necessary.

Comment: See my edited answer. There might be other/nicer ways, but this works for me. As an alternative, one could append another variable like the model name.