# Avoid generating temporary files with .mos files together in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

I set the working directory in Dymola:
[image]

But when I run a script, the temporary files are generated in the same directory as the .mos file, instead of the working directory in Dymola.
My question is :
How could I make the temporary files generated always in the working directory?
[image]

Comment: you might be able to find a workaround using code snippets from this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54764226/mkdir-from-dymola-mos-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behavior of Dymola is to change the working directory to the script directory when scripts are run. To prevent that, set the flag

```
Advanced.ChangeToScriptDirectory=false;
```