# How to automatically delete Dymolas build files after simulation?

Tags: modelica, dymola

Every time I simulate in Dymola, a number of "useless" (for me) files are created in the working directory - i.e. `dsfinal.txt`, `dsin.txt`, `dslog.txt`, `dsmodel.c`, `dymosim.exe`. I find it annoying as it messes up my directory.

Is there a way to select only the desired output files to be kept after the simulations, without the need of manually deleting the undesired ones?

Comment: somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54764226/mkdir-from-dymola-mos-script
I use that mos script to always create a "temporary" working directory.

Answer (score 5):

Those are temporary, but necessary files for Dymola. As far as I know there is no option to delete them automatically. Of course you could script that, but I don't see a real point to it and those files are used by some functionality - e.g. `dsfinal.txt` is used when as simulation is continued.

Some notes: Those files are created in the working directory - which should contain temporary files only. The working directory can be set via the GUI using File -> Options -> Settings:

[image: Dymola: Options -> Settings]

A rather common problem is, that there is a `Open` and a `Load` function in Dymola:
[image: Dymola: Load vs Open]

As the description states, `Load` does not influence the working directory, whereas `Open` sets it to the directory from which a file is opened. The latter is also true for opening files e.g. via a double-click from the explorer. So usually it is better to go with `Load`.

My advice would be to separate the directories in which models/packages are stored and the working directory. This way the working directories content can be fully deleted basically anytime...