# Dymola - Is there any difference between "Open" and "Load" files?

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I’ve been using Dymola (version 2017) for three months and I’d just like to ask a simple issue that I think about it nearly every day. Is there any difference between the file tool **“Open”** and **“Load"**? I'm used to use **Load** for “load” the library packages and **Open** for “open” the model files, but I've tried to switch them few times and I didn’t notice any difference. I guess that it isn’t relevant and actually it’s just out of curiosity, but maybe someone in this community is able to shed some light on why there are two buttons. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69797890/how-to-automatically-delete-dymolas-build-files-after-simulation/69806518#69806518

Comment: You may ask for a Dymola upgrade, there have been 11 releases since Dymola 2017.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both load your .mo files into the package browser. But *Open* changes the working directory to the location of the .mo file, whereas *Load* does not.

From the command line:

```
openModel("lib.mo", changeDirectory=false) // corresponds to load
openModel("lib.mo")                        // corresponds to open
```

You can check your current working directory by typing `cd` on the command line.